# how to do the conditional formating for based on the limit of the characters in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I want to have conditional formating based on the length of the chars of the cells in the column.

- if the length>100 then mark it red and possibly in another cell, count how many reds or how many cells are length > 100.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

The `LEN` function allows you to get the length of a string in a cell. For example if the cell A3 contained "hello", `LEN(A3)` would output 3.

To make the cell red, you can right-click on the cell and select conditional formatting. Then under the "Format cells if" select custom formula. You can then use `=LEN(CELL_NUMBER)>100` as the formula and select red as the color to set it as.

You can also use the `COUNTIF()` to get the total count of cells with length greater than 100. Example usage is here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en

Comment: thanks. =LEN(CELL_NUMBER)>100 can be applied on the range?

Comment: e.g. =LEN(I4:I)>100

Comment: I dont believe LEN supports range but COUNTIF does. This should let you effectively sum the number of cells in a range where the LEN>100